# jQuery Filter Issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
_OnFilterChange() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $("#courseFilter");
  filter = input.val();

  $('li').each(function() {
    a = $("#title").val();
    var current = $('li');

    if (a.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      current.addClass("active");
    } else {
      current.removeClass("active");
    };
  });
}
```

The script is designed to take the contents of the input for `courseFilter` and search the Titles of all the `li` in a list. Where there is a match (partial or full) a class for active is added or removed from the specific `li` that is matched.

For some reason its either showing everything (when no text is in the `courseFilter`) or its hiding everything when I type anything in the box.

I think its down to selecting the `li` but not sure how to isolate the `li`.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit - HTML

```
<div class="calendar-occasions__course-filter">
    <input type="text" id="courseFilter" placeholder="Start searching for your course..." title="Type in a name">
</div>


<ul id="gallery" class="calendar-occasions__occasions">
    <li class="calendar-occasions__occasion" id="event-@b" data-id="@b">
        <div class="calendar-occasions__occasion-outer" data-calendar-ocasion-id="@categoryEvent.Id">
            <div class="calendar-occasions__occasion-inner calendar-occasion" data-component="components/toggle-class" data-toggle-class__class-name="calendar-occasion--show-breakdown" data-sync-height-element-key="panel">
                <div class="calendar-occasion__header" data-sync-height-element-key="header">
                    <div class="calendar-occasion__header-left">
                        @if (categoryEvent.StartSession == null)
                        {
                        <span class="calendar-occasion__date">
                            @Html.DateString(categoryEvent.Start)
                        </span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                    <span class="calendar-occasion__date">
                        @Html.DateString(categoryEvent.StartSession.Start)
                    </span>
                        }
                        @if (categoryEvent.ActiveSessions.Count > 1)
                        {
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="calendar-occasion__breakdown" data-toggle-class__hit>Session<br>Breakdown</a>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="calendar-occasion__header-right">

                        <h3 id="title" class="calendar-occasion__start-session">@categoryEvent.Title</h3>
                        <h3 class="calendar-occasion__location">Bridgend</h3>
                        <span class="calendar-occasion__time-span">@categoryEvent.StartSession.Start.ToString("h:mmtt") - @categoryEvent.StartSession.End.ToString("h:mmtt") </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems that you have multiple #title (one per li) it's not a valid DOM. This can't work, ID must be unique. replace your id with class

Comment: Well two things.  It's changing everything because your `current` is `$('li');`, which is a global lookup, rather than `$(this)` which would be the li being iterated over.  The second concern is you are doing the same thing for the title, which as an id, will only return a single element, so it is odd that you are doing that lookup in a loop.

Comment: @31piy added html for context - there will be multiple li as it is dynamically generated

Comment: As Taplar said, `var current = $('li');` will select *every `<li>` on the page*, thus when you do `current.addClass` or `current.removeClass`, you'll modify *all* of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id must be unique on a page, use class instead of duplicate id. 
You can get actual element by using `$(this)`.

Example of working code:

```js
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("li.title").each(function(){
   ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1 && value != "") ? $(this).addClass("active") : $(this).removeClass("active");
  })
})
```

```css
.active{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Seach in list" id="filter" />

<ul>
  <li class="title">a</li>
  <li class="title">ab</li>
  <li class="title">abc</li>
  <li class="title">abcd</li>
  <li class="title">abcde</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and if the field that needs to be searched is a child element of the li - how is the correct way to code this?

Comment: Just target the child instead of the current element... There's a `find()` method

Comment: great thanks for this - one final issue is that it's only filtering a few characters - what do i need to adjust to filter more than 2 letters?

Comment: @PaulAlmond What do you mean ? This works for more than 2 letters.

Comment: In my implementation say I have title values of team and certificate and i search for team team is not showing but it partially shows if i type t

Comment: i've implemented: 

var value = $("#courseFilter").val();
 $('li.calendar-occasions__occasion').each(function () {
   ($(this).find("#title").text().indexOf(value) > -1) ? $(this).addClass("active") : $(this).removeClass("active");
 })
  }

with the function being called by this._courseFilter.on('keyup', ::this._OnFilterChange);

Comment: One more time, ID MUST be unique in your page. You must have only one element who have the `id="title"`. Use Class. I can't help you with this piece of  code. I juste need example of what you have if your HTML and what to you expect (like my example)

Comment: figured it out - I needed to include toUpperCase to remove the case sensitivity of the search. your implementation works as i require. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Alexis, you need to use `$(this)`:

```
_OnFilterChange() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $("#courseFilter");
  filter = input.val();

  $('li').each(function() {
    a = $("#title").val();
    var current = $(this);  // <-- here, replace 'li' by this

    if (a.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      current.addClass("active");
    } else {
      current.removeClass("active");
    };
  });
}
```

That should be sufficient to see things work as expected in terms of "`li`".

Note that variable `a` should be set outside of the loop since its value does not vary depending on the `li`. Some of your variables are not used and could be removed. It's also a good idea to set the variable as it is declared as follow:

```
_OnFilterChange() {
  var input = input = $("#courseFilter"),
      filter = input.val(),
      a = $("#title").val();

  $('li').each(function() {
    var current = $(this);  // <-- here, replace 'li' by this

    if (a.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      current.addClass("active");
    } else {
      current.removeClass("active");
    };
  });
}
```